# Run concurrent tests Cucumber/Capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am looking for some assistance on where to start to run concurrent tests with Cucumber/Capybara. I need to do this without the 'parallel_tests' gem.the reason being is I can't seem to be able to have separate users login for each process.

I was thinking that I could have a shared pool of users, most likely in a array but I can't share this data across separate processes with the gem.

Some feedback I have received is to use IO.pipe but as yet do not know enough about it.

I have a standalone Cucumber framework, no Rails etc.

Comment: I've achieved this using a rake multitask before, but I think that approach only makes sense if you can sensibly divide up your tests into separate rake tasks.  e.g. running a full suite of tests on different tablets in parallel or runnign tests in different browsers.  If you just want to speed up a test run then you'd end up arbitrarily dividing your suite into chunks, which isn't very nice / won't scale well.  What is the context for wanting to run in parallel?

Comment: I ideally would like to run 2/3 features at a time, each feature will login as a different user (using sso) so cant have same user logging in twice. need to have a pool of users and which can be shared across multiple processes. does that make sense? parrallel_tests does seem to fork its processes but cant figure out how to setup a pipe to share data

Comment: If you use Thread.current['USER'] as the variable in all of your tests, then you can set that in each thread in your before hook.  If you had your user pool set in a global or env variable you could collect the username to use from it.  If you want to cycle them you could have them in an array with another var to mark them as in use or not in use and have your before hook pick the first one that's not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post my solution in case it helps anyone else. I have ended up separating the user pool away from my application and storing them using [Redis](http://redis.io/).

I then have a simple method that will pick a random user from a Set in Redis and put it back once it has finished with it

```
def choose_redis_user
  @redis = Redis.new
  @randUser = @redis.spop("users")
  $user_username = @redis.hget(@randUser, "username")
  $user_password = @redis.hget(@randUser, "password")
end

def return_redis_user
  @redis.sadd("users", @randUser)
end
```

Then within my tests i can run

```
login_page.username.set($user_username)
login_page.password.set($user_password)
```

This works really well with multiple parallel_tests